# How do I use a specific variable of an object that is in another class?

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to modify the toString method. I have an object called 'p' which has 2 doubles as attributes, in this case, 5.0 and 6.0 which are 'x' and 'y' values, respectively.

The brackets, inside the String converter "< Point >", should be printing the "x" of p, the "y" of p, while in the circle it should print the radius. Sure enough printing the radius works, but I'm unsure as to how I'm supposed to specify "x" of p and "y" of p.

Class Circle:

```
package packageName;

public class Circle {

public Point center;
public double radius;

public Circle(Point a, double b) {
    this.center = a;
    this.radius = b;
}

    public String toString() {
        String converter = "<Circle(<Point(" + (x of p) + ", " + (y of p) + ")>, " + this.radius + ")>";
        return converter;
    }


    public static void main(String args []) {
        Point p = new Point(5.0, 6.0);
        Circle c = new Circle(p, 4.0);
        c.toString();
    }
}
```

Class Point:

```
package packageName;
public class Point{


public double x;
public double y;

public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public String toString() {
    String input = "<Point(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")>";
    return input;

  }
}
```

Comment: step 1: declare your variables as private instead of public. step 2: implement getter/setter methods

Comment: or just use the value of `p.toString ();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying that you want to print "x" of "p" and "y" of "p" in the `toString` method of `Cirlce`, but `toString` does not know anything about `p` because `p` is declared locally in the `main` method.

In the `main` method, you created `p` and passed it to the first parameter of `Circle`, which then gets assigned to `center`. So `center` stores the same thing as `p`. You should use `center.x` and `center.y`:

```
String converter = "<Circle(<Point(" + center,x + ", " + center.y + ")>, " + this.radius + ")>";
return converter;
```

Alternatively, you could call `center.toString()` directly:

```
String converter = "<Circle(" + c.toString() + ", " + this.radius + ")>";
return converter;
```

Notice how I used the syntax `foo.bar` to mean "bar of foo". This is dot notation, and it seems like you are unfamiliar with this.

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a local variable to the `main` method, so the variable `p` itself cannot be used at the place where you want use it.

But I have good news – you're passing in a `Point` instance as argument to the `Circle` constructor, and you're storing it in the `center` field.

You can reference it as `this.center` or just `center`. To reference `x` of the specified `Point` instance, use

```
this.center.x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use center.x and center.y as follows:

```
String converter = "<Circle(<Point(" + this.center.x + ", " + this.center.y + ")>, " + this.radius + ")>";
```

Or you just make x and y variable of Point class as private and use getter method as follows:

```
private double x;
private double y;

public double getX(){
    return this.x;
}
public double getY(){
    return this.y;
}
```

And use

```
String converter = "<Circle(<Point(" + this.center.getX() + ", " + this.center.getY() + ")>, " + this.radius + ")>";
```

Comment: Interesting, why do I have to make the variables private to make use of getters?

Comment: Actually when you are using class, then it's instance variables should be private. And this actually supports abstraction property. This is good practice to make instance variables private and the usage of getter/setter methods.